# will response not be cached after Last-Modified + max-age?

Tags: cache-control, last-modified

Say today (Aug 30 2012) an web server returns an image with http header
  Age: 4387905 (50 days: since last modified to today)
  Last-Modified: 10 Jul 2012
  Cache Control: public , max-age=3153600 (1 year)
  Expires: 10 July 2013

All looks correct.

My question is, what happens after "Expires: 10 July 2013"?
After that, I guess Last-Modified: 10 Jul 2012 and max-age: 1 year will not change.

then after  10 Jul 2013, the image can  no longer be cached, it expires immediately, each time request it, it will go to server to get a new copy, right?

I believe it is not the case, but I hope someone can confirm it.

Comment: Similar question on the same topic: is max-age relative to the date of request or the last modifed header?